# Why am i getting a segmantation fault in the code for mergesort?

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort

I have written the following code for mergesort and getting segmentation fault.The function merge() is working fine but there is something wrong with mergesort().
What could be the possible reason for segmentation fault?Also can there be any improvement in the code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(vector<int> a,vector<int> b){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    vector<int> result;
    while(i<a.size()&&j<b.size()){
        if(a[i]<b[j]){
            result.push_back(a[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            result.push_back(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<a.size()){
        result.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j<b.size()){
        result.push_back(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}



vector<int> mergesort(vector<int> a,int low,int hi){
    vector<int> b,c,result;
    if(low==hi)
        return a;
    b=mergesort(a,low,(low+hi)/2);
    c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2+1,hi);
    result=merge(b,c);
    return result;
}
int main(){
    vector<int> a=mergesort({5,2,1,3,4,6},0,5);
    for(auto &i:a)
        cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `if(low==hi)return a;`? Also `b,c` will share `a[(hi+low)/2]` element which is not what you want because second range will never hit `low==hi` Debugging your code would find it in 30secs. Improvement might be to pass vector arguments by const references, returning by value is ok here.

Comment: @Quimby Returning vectors by value from a recursively-called function would be  inefficient as well. Merge sort typically uses a single auxiliary array and merges from the original array to the auxiliary one or vice versa (these two options alternate) to prevent unnecessary copying.

Comment: @Quimby what are the advantages of passing the vector using const reference in this particular case?

Comment: @vedantlodha Reference because you don't  need to copy the vectors all the time. Also it's a good practice to mark them `const` because the function doesn't modify them..

Answer (score 2):

```
if(low==hi)
    return a;
```

You are returning the entire vector here. You should return a vector with just one element.

```
 if(low==hi)
    return {a[low]};
```

And

```
b=mergesort(a,low,(low+hi)/2);
c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2,hi);
```

`(low+hi)/2` is a common index that will be processed by both the calls. Consider `mergesort(a, 0, 1)`, this will result in `mergesort(a, 0, 0)` and `mergesort(a, 0, 1)`. So the call to `mergesort(a, 0, 1)` never ends, this causes the segmentaion fault. You need,

```
c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2 + 1,hi);
```